# Is it possible to create a CRUD Form based on many tables on web2py?

Tags: python, html, web2py

I am trying to mantain some info scattered across 6 tables using web2py.

I have read that web2py have a CRUD component? that allows to make CRUD operations on a given table. I was thinking if it was possible to create one form with some of the model tables/fields (not all fields) and make CRUD operations using that form?

If so, how? If not, what would be the best approach to acoomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is a somewhat more manual and involved process to handle multiple tables via a single form, but it can be done via `SQLFORM.factory` and manual inserts after form processing. For details, see [this section](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07/forms-and-validators#One-form-for-multiple-tables) of the documentation.

Of course, you can take an even more manual approach and just code the form from scratch in HTML or via the `FORM` helper, and then use the submitted form variables to do the necessary inserts.